# Eventqueue query crashing the CD site

Tags: sql-database, event-queue

I have a single CD CM 8.2 instance of sitecore.

We have a job that is running at a particular time everyday which publishes around a 1000 items. Our CD server crashes everytime the job runs and the query that blocks the website is:

```
)SELECT [EventType], [InstanceType], [InstanceData], [InstanceName], [UserName], [Stamp], [Created] 
FROM [EventQueue] 
WHERE ([InstanceName] <> @targetInstance AND [RaiseGlobally] = 1 OR [InstanceName] = @targetInstance AND [RaiseLocally] = 1) AND [Stamp] >= CAST(@fromTimestamp AS TIMESTAMP) 
ORDER BY [Stam
```

Our DB configuration is as follows:

1. AWS RDS instance - db.m4.xlarge — 4 vCPU, 16 GiB RAM, 1000 IOPS
2. CD server is 16 GB RAM

What would be the best way to resolve this issue?

Upgrade the IOPS of the server? Upgrade the RAM?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the logs?

Comment: How many rows there are in eventqueue table now? Try cleaning the queue and starting with empty one?

Comment: What do you mean "blocks the website"? Is the query taking a long time to respond during which time the CD is unresponsive? Does it return an unexpected result which causes the Sitecore application to crash? Something else?

Comment: This implies your event queue table has more records than is reasonable (reasonable is dependent on your specs which seem okay). It would be very helpful to know if you're dealing with 1,000 rows, 10,000 rows or 100,000 rows.

Comment: It does sound to me that you have a lot of records in your event queue.  I recommend looking at this post on how to manage the queues and keep them clean. https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/sitecore-event-queue-how-to-clean-it-and-why/

Comment: The event queue has 40000 records. I have increased the frequency of the event queue clean up agent. Hopefully that should help

Comment: Blocks the website as in the website times out (504)

Comment: There are no errors on the logs just this query taking ages